# iOS SQLite Sum and retrieve data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I am creating in my iOS application. A series of numbers are being stored in this database. I want to sum the entire column, and return the data to be displayed within the application.

Everything writing to the DB is working properly, but I am stuck trying to return the summed data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(void) dataReturn: (NSString *) tableNamed{
    NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SUM(column1) AS data1 FROM myDB", tableNamed];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [myData UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) ==SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){

            int *field2 = (int *) sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);

            NSString *myString =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", field2];

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello Nathan making a call as

```
[self  dataReturn:@"Bill"];
```

to function

```
-(void)dataReturn:(NSString *)tableName{

    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SUM(price) AS TOTAL FROM %@", tableName];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    int field1 =  sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                    NSLog(@"The sum is  %d ", field1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will Fetch you desired data. The schema for Table "Bill" is "CREATE TABLE Bill (price  double,quantity INTEGER)". The result fetched will have columns indexed from "0" so we pass 0 for first column. Hope you can take some hint from it. Cheers!!

```
int field1 =  sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [`sqlite3_column_int`](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob) docs:

> The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0.

Additionally, that function returns an `int`, not an `int*`. Try:

```
int field2 = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm still getting a value of 0 if I trace the variable (I have viewed the db and verified I do have data in there, I should be getting 61 as a response) ...

Comment: Is myDB the name of a table in your database?  I notice that you are not using the tableNamed parameter in the myData string.  Also, in addition to getting rid of the pointer * in front of field 2, make sure that you are also using 0 instead of 1 as the 2nd parameter in the sqlite3_column_int function.  (And finally, make sure to use %d instead of %@ in your initWithFormat method.)